# CreateJS pressup/click won't trigger when target movie is played on mousedown/pressmove

Tags: createjs

I have a project where I need to make flash movie as an interactive game. Because, flash is already (or soon will be) obsolete for most of browsers, I've decided this game must be based on HTML5/JS. Because most of the graphics and animations are already done in this Flash movie (and I have its source), I'm developing it using Adobe Flash and CreateJS technology (HTML5 + Canvas + JS). So far, I like this solution pretty much, though I have an issue which I could not solve yet.
The game is a simple drag&drop matching game. The problem I have is shortly described in the question title and I will try to explain it here more detailed:

```
label.on('mousedown', function() {
    //this.image.bg.gotoAndStop(2);
});

label.on('pressmove', function(evt) {
        this.x = getStageX(evt.stageX);
        this.y = getStageY(evt.stageY);
        currentStage.setChildIndex(this, currentStage.getNumChildren() - 1);
        stage.update();
});

label.on('pressup', function(evt) {
    console.log('Hi! I'm mouseup event!')
    this.x = labelInitX;
    this.y = labelInitY;
    this.image.bg.gotoAndStop(0);
});
```

Above, you can see simplified 3 event handlers I use. Everything is working fine until I uncomment second line - `//this.image.bg.gotoAndStop(2);`. When I do this, the `pressup` event does not trigger mostly, which is rather strange, because some times it does trigger (2-3 times out of 10), so the label sticks with the pointer until I press the button again.
Is this some bug or I simply does not understand something about the CreateJS and its event handlers. I tried different combinations of this. Used `click` instead of `pressup`, placing `this.image.bg.gotoAndStop(2);` inside the `pressmove` handler. Replacing `pressmove` handler with the `stage.on('stagepressmove', handler)`. None did not work. `this.image.bg.gotoAndStop(2);` - this thing simply updates the timeframe (change the background image of the label). I do can change this image programatically (without playing timeframes) and I'm almost sure that the issue will be fixes, though I'd like to understand for myself what is wrong here or what I'm doing wrong with the event handlers.

Another, less important thing, but would be useful to know is why when `pressmove` event is running, the CreateJS objects stop receiving event triggers about `rollover` or `mouseover`? In DOM, by default event bubbling is working until you stop it with stopPropagation. How does it work here with CreateJS? Seems that bubbling is simply turned off here by default. How can I turn it on?

Answer (score 2):

I thought I might shed some light on what I think is going on.

The normal mouse events "click", "mouseup", "rollover", "rollout", etc all function by the stage determine what the "target" of the mouse event was by default the target is the lowest-level thing that is interacted with. If you contents change while the mouse is down, it will not count as the same target when the mouseup occurs. Since positions are not re-checked without moving the mouse, the mouseover, mouseout, rollover, and rollout events may function oddly as well.

Conversely, the "pressmove" and "pressup" events do not care what is under the mouse once something is pressed. The target will always be what was pressed, which allows you to move the mouse out of the object (or even remove it), and still receive events from it. This also ensures that you receive a pressup event even if you release outside the object.

As @RandyPrad mentioned, the hitArea may solve your issue. By specifying a hit area, you are overriding the contents of your clip, so your target should always be the container (MovieClip) instead of its contents. That way no matter what is pressed inside the movieclip, it is the same target when you release. You can also get the same effect using the mouseChildren property.

```
movieClip.mouseChildren = false;
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Please check your hit area of the button.

i think that your are playing image inside the btn is animating

please use this link http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/hitArea.html